# Keep distinct records within each group

Tags: mysql

I have a table called School, my first column is the classroom number and column 2 is the student id, and column 3 is time. For instance (1, 123456, 07:00) means that student 123456 enters classroom 1 at 07:00. I Would like to perform an operation that get rid of duplicated students within each classroom. Usually, this would just be

```
SELECT DISTINCT student FROM school
```

However, I want to do this for each classroom. In other words, there might be duplicate students across the whole table but only unique students within each classroom. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `GROUP BY classroom, student` (and removing the `DISTINCT`). If you want to enforce this in the table by default (and not just on a query), you can provide a `UNIQUE` constraint across the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GROUP BY function on both classroom and student instead of using DISTINCT.

```
SELECT student
FROM school
GROUP BY classroom, student
```